# Samsung Smart Switch - Do I need the same version of an app on both phones?

Tags: samsung, data-transfer, samsung-smart-switch

I mean to transfer only selected apps from my J7 2015 (Phone #1, P1) to my new J7 Prime (Phone #2, P2) using Samsung Smart Switch (SSS).

Some of these apps are already installed in P2.
Since different versions of an app may use a different file structure to handle its data and work, I conceive that SSS is not smart enough to be aware of this (it would be too much asking from SSS), and therefore that the switch requires first to have the same version of the apps to be switched in both phones, for the transferred data to be operative in the new phone.

**Is that correct or not?**
**Can anyone provide authoritative answers/links?**
**Did anyone had specific experiences with different versions of apps (which app/version in each phone)?**

PS: At first, I had a non-updated version in my old phone, and SSS was not going through (and not throwing any error or warning message). Then I updated SSS and it worked. So at least SSS requires some degree of "similarity" in its own versions.

PS2: In some apps, I can confirm that login info was not properly transferred, and I had to login again in the new phone.

Answer (score 1):

For many of the applications that I transferred, only the app itself is transferred, not the data, so it becomes irrelevant if the versions are the same or not.

I do not know if this is always the case.